# How to use Facebook Graph API for IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to have an iPhone application using Graph API where in a user can get his/her Facebook wall updates. (Something similar to functionality of Home Tab on Facebook).

**I have gone through this tutorial of Graph API for iphone**

http://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

**Here the problem we are facing is:**

It has all the functionality but it dumps all the code in the console. How to display this information on a User Interface (View).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON to parse the o/p which is coming in the console window. You can create a dictionary and save the result in this dictionary and then using the objectForKey you can display the particular result in the iphone.

Comment: but can we display the response in a facebook page itself?? As if we are displaying the home page of the facebook. Please help . Thanks

Comment: the facebook page that u r seeing when the user login is a webview so u cant show the result in that page. But u can show the result else where in the project.